# Content-length header lost during request (django)

Tags: django, http, nginx, header, uwsgi

Using

```
    clen = os.path.getsize(the_file)
    response['content-disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    response['content-length'] = clen
    return response
```

Results in a response header with only the content disposition, but not the content-length
If I add a non-sense header like

```
    response['bla'] = 'some non-sense'
```

it appears perfectly in the response. Is there somewhere else where headers are being overwritten or something. I'm using nginx with uwsgi.

Comment: printing clen yields a valid (non-zero) length

Comment: It's might be your Nginx config - for example Nginx [doesn't send the content-length header when using dynamic gzip](https://serverfault.com/questions/529621/forcing-nginx-to-send-content-length-headers-when-serving-static-files-with-gzip)

Answer (score 0):

Content-Length **is** sent in the headers when using application/octet-stream as Content-Type.